# Как сохранить сообщение от пользователя моего Чат-Бота Вконтакте

Tags: python, вконтакте

Для написания бота я использую vkbottle. В качестве базы данных - sqlite3. Мне нужно сохранить все сообщение, которое пришлет пользователь после нажатия кнопки "Купить". Также видел, что в vkbottle можно так:
@bot.on.message(text="Купить (buy)"). Как в этом случае, сохранить только (buy)
(как заносить в бд я знаю)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Используйте SQL оператор INSERT для добавления в базу данных, у вас для этого должна быть таблица

Comment: @timur, вызвать commit у connection. Если соединение поместить в `with`, то это будет автоматически: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit и https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager. Кст, а зачем вы удалили код?

Comment: @gil9red мне нужно было само логирование.

Answer (score 0):

Текст сообщения хранится в `message.text`. Можно получить любые значения из `@bot.on.message(text="<!>")` или из`@bot.on.message()`.

```py
import sqlite3
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message

bot = Bot(token="token")
con = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
cur = con.cursor()


@bot.on.message(text="Купить <value>")
async def handler(message: Message, value: str):
    text = message.text  # Сообщение целиком
    text = text.replace("Купить ", "")  # Значение <value> из сообщения

    cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO goods VALUES ({value})")
    return None


bot.run_forever()
cur.close()
con.commit()
con.close()
```